# NPM Install from package.json specifying registry

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

In my `.nprmc` file, I have specified a specific internal registry (Artifactory) for my npm installs.

My question though is, is it possible to do an `npm install` for the dependencies listed in my `package.json` specifying a different registry for some of the modules?

Example:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@quasar/extras": "^1.0.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "quasar": "^2.3.4",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.1",
    "extra-module": "^2.3.1" -- I need to get this module from a different registry
  },
```

How can I make npm install (from package.json) to download `extra-module` from a different registry?

Thanks!

Comment: Can the module be given a namespace? npm can be configured to look elsewhere for any modules under a `@namespace` so `@me/extra-module`

Comment: I would need to consume the module though as ```require('extra-module')```. Do you know if this is possible when using a namespace? Or does it always have to be ```require('@me/extra-module')``` then? This ```extra-module``` is being consumed by another module which I wouldn't be able to modify, so I need to maintain the name (as far as consumption goes) as is.

Comment: Yeah the different namespace would change the require path unfortunately.